# InstallShield 5.5 - Array of strings

Tags: installshield

I "inherited" an old InstallShield 5.5 project which I need to modify.
One change I need to do involves a list of strings I have to populate.
I am looking to to define an array of strings. I tried this:

```
STRING ListOfStrings[10];
```

But when I try this:

```
ListOfStrings[1] = "test";
```

I get an error: error  C8038: numeric value required

But this does work:

ListOfStrings[1] = 123;

Looks like the declaration of the ListOfStrings is of an array of chars, not an array of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, the notation `STRING str[10]` declares an array of 10 characters. (STRING itself is a resizable array of characters.) InstallScript is not a modern language. It's somewhat of a cross between C and VB, but changes several things. If you want a list of strings, you probably need to use the [List Processing Functions](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefList_processing_functions.htm), in particular declaring and creating a list of strings:

```
LIST lst;
STRING szString;
// : : :
lst = ListCreate(STRINGLIST);
szString = "test";
ListAddString(lst, szString, AFTER);
// : : :
```

In addition you should use some error checking, like that shown on the [ListAddString example](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefListAddString_example.htm).

In less common situations it may be useful to declare an array of `POINTER` objects (or optionally `WPOINTER` objects in later versions). (Update your question if you think that might be necessary).